# My weights in my simple Neural Network (Binary Classification) do not stabilize and keep increasing

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am currently on a problem that needs me to create a simple neural network to solve a simple task : with a set of data, determine if a cell is Benign or Malignant. My weights wouldn't stabilize over generations, and I encounter Nan values at some point. My prediction is either all ones or all zeros. My NN has an input layer of 30 neurons, 2 hidden layers of 10 neurons each and an output layer of 2 neurons.

I have tried to implement the NN myself with some functions:

Init_params to initialize my weights and bias:

```
def init_params():
    W1 = 0.01 * np.random.rand(10, 30)
    b1 = 0.01 * np.random.rand(10, 1)
    W2 = 0.01 * np.random.rand(10, 10)
    b2 = 0.01 * np.random.rand(10, 1)
    W3 = 0.01 * np.random.rand(2, 10)
    b3 = 0.01 * np.random.rand(2, 1)
    return W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3
```

Sigmoid and softmax to act as activation functions, Sigmoid for hidden layers and softmax for the output layer :

```
def _sigmoid(x):
    x = x.astype(np.float64)
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def softmax(Z):
    Z = Z.astype(np.float64)
    exp = np.exp(Z - np.max(Z))
    return exp / exp.sum(axis=0)
```

forward_prop to do the forward propagation of my NN :

```
def forward_prop(W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3, X):
    Z1 = W1.dot(X) + b1
    A1 = _sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = W2.dot(A1) + b2
    A2 = _sigmoid(Z2)
    Z3 = W3.dot(A2) + b3
    A3 = softmax(Z3)
    return A1, Z1, A2, Z2, A3
```

back_prop to do the back propagation of my NN with the derivative of sigmoid and a one_hot_encoder to encode my true result :

```
def one_hot_encoder(Y):
    one_hot_Y = []
    for y in Y:
        if y == "B":
            one_hot_Y.append([0, 1])
        else:
            one_hot_Y.append([1, 0])
    one_hot_Y = np.array(one_hot_Y)
    return one_hot_Y.T


def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return _sigmoid(x) * (1 - _sigmoid(x))


def back_prop(A1, Z1, A2, Z2, W2, A3, W3, X, Y):
    m = Y.size
    dZ3 = A3 - one_hot_encoder(Y)
    dW3 = 1 / m * dZ3.dot(A2.T)
    db3 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ3, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    dZ2 = W3.T.dot(dZ3) * sigmoid_derivative(Z2)
    dW2 = 1 / m * dZ2.dot(A1.T)
    db2 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    dZ1 = W2.T.dot(dZ2) * sigmoid_derivative(Z1)
    dW1 = 1 / m * dZ1.dot(X.T)
    db1 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return dW1, db1, dW2, db2, dW3, db3
```

update_params to update my weights and bias :

```
def update_params(W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3, dW1, db1, dW2, db2, dW3, db3, learning_rate):
    W1 = W1 - learning_rate * dW1
    b1 = b1 - learning_rate * np.reshape(db1, (10,1))
    W2 = W2 - learning_rate * dW2
    b2 = b2 - learning_rate * np.reshape(db2, (10,1))
    W3 = W3 - learning_rate * dW3
    b3 = b3 - learning_rate * np.reshape(db3, (2,1))
    return W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3
```

Gradient descent function to do all the stuff, along a get prediction and get accuracy function to calculate the accuracy of my model through epochs :

```
def get_predictions(A3):
    print(np.argmax(A3, 0))
    return np.argmax(A3, 0)


def get_accuracy(predictions, Y):
    predictions_mapped = np.where(predictions == 0, 'M', 'B')
    return np.sum(predictions_mapped == Y) / Y.size


def gradient_descent(X, Y, iterations, learning_rate):
    W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3 = init_params()
    for i in range(iterations):
        A1, Z1, A2, Z2, A3 = forward_prop(W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3, X)
        dW1, db1, dW2, db2, dW3, db3 = back_prop(A1, Z1, A2, Z2, W2, A3, W3, X, Y)
        W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3 = update_params(W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3, dW1, db1, dW2, db2, dW3, db3, learning_rate)
        if i % 20 == 0:
            print("Iteration: ", i)
            predictions = get_predictions(A3)
            print("Accuracy: ", get_accuracy(predictions, Y))
    return W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3
```

my main where I get the data and I divide it into two parts one for the training and one for the validation (test), I scale my data in it too :

```
def scaling(X):
    mean = np.mean(X)
    std = np.std(X)
    normalized_arr = (X - mean) / std
    return normalized_arr


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("usage: mlp.py [dataset]")
    else:
        try:
            data = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])
            data.dropna(inplace=True)
            data = data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

            train_size = int(len(data) * 0.8)
            data_train = data[:train_size]
            data_test = data[train_size:]

            data_train = data_train.drop(axis=1, columns=["Index", "Id"])
            data_train = np.array(data_train.T)
            Y_train = data_train[0]
            X_train = data_train[1:]
            X_train_scaled = scaling(X_train)

            W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3 = gradient_descent(X_train_scaled, Y_train, 1, 0.01)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(sys.argv[1] + " not found.")
```

I have tried several things, such as printing the shape and content of everything, such as weights or biases. When I print the content of A3, it shows me a matrix where the values are all larger on one side, even from the first iteration. So, the result of np.argmax is either all ones or all zeros.
Where did I made a mistake on this code ?